# Create a helper or function in webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have webmatrix webpage with four categories to search for a product. The first categories has radio button and its category Design. Second is dropdownlist for category Supplier. Third is dropdownlist for category Products and lastly radio button for properties.

When a user selects in Design category, using AJAX the results are displayed same with other categories.

I have an if statement in to each category. Below is the if ... else block.

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Design"])){
   var design = Request.Form["Design"];
   var sql2 = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM plastics WHERE Design=@0";
   var sql = "SELECT * FROM plastics WHERE Design=@0  OFFSET @1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @2 ROWS  ONLY";
   count = db.QueryValue(sql2, design);
   var data = db.Query(sql, design, offset, pageSize);

  // code for webgrid. This where I will call the function 

  } else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Supplier"])) {

    var design = Request.Form["Design"];
    var supplier = Request.Form["Supplier"];
   var sql2 = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM plastics WHERE Design=@0 AND Supplier=@1";
   var sql = "SELECT * FROM plastics WHERE Design=@0  AND Supplier=@1 OFFSET @2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @3 ROWS  ONLY";
   count = db.QueryValue(sql2, design,supplier );
   var data = db.Query(sql, design,supplier, offset, pageSize);

   // code for webgrid. This where I will call the function

    } else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Product"])) {
     .......
   // code for webgrid. This where I will call the function

    } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Propeties"])) {
    ........
   // code for webgrid. This where I will call the function
    } else  { 

   // code for webgrid. This where I will call the function
    }
  and so on...
```

My intention is to have a helper or function that is called, something like this:

```
@functions {
public static HtmlString webgridpage(IEnumerable<object> data)
{

    var grid = new WebGrid(data,canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 10 );
     <div id="grid">
<div id="table">
    @grid.GetHtml(    
        tableStyle : "table",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(

        grid.Column("Supplier", "Supplier Name"),
        grid.Column("Telephone"),
        grid.Column("Description", style: "descr"),
        grid.Column("Stock"),
        grid.Column("City", "Location")
    )
   )
   return new HtmlString(webgridpage.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

}

I need help with datatype of the Query in *var data = db.Query(sql, supplier, offset, pageSize);* as this is what is passed to my function. I tried IEnumerable and it gave me an error.

Also before the function what reference must I use? I want my function to return a webgrid or html.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? 
Does this [fiddle match your dropdowns and radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/aZpwL/1/)?

Comment: I got the answer thanks a lot. I appreciate your your concern.